Altium CircuitMaker - Polygon Pour issue - Does not apper
I impored a model from Altium Designer into Altium CircuitMaker.
When I updated my Polygon Pour, then the total orange area (GND plane) disappear. But it's still there, it's not poured as it used to be.
So what can be the issue here?




The 3D model can be found here https://file.io/uxQZY0ilgdmN
To insert that model inte Altium CircuitMaker, you need select the file here and select Project -> Add Existing Document


Here is the answer.
Just press this button...then do repour....done. It took me a while to figure that out.

